# Add inline styling to a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using CMS (MURA) to create the form. The form works correctly and function fine. However, the Submit button is not centered and I would like to add inline styling to the div that contains the Submit button (The highlighted div is where I would like to add the inline styling).

I know I could go to the form and just add the styling. However, I am unable to access the form/modify the styling directly.

[image]

I have done the following to target that particular div where it contains the Submit button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[class='']").css("text-align", "center");
});
```

However, it does not target the div. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Update:** I have tried the following approach to target the input that is within the Mura Form. However, it still does not target the input at all. Can anyone explain if my approach is incorrect?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#frm45EAED3E155D020135053C5229A9497A input[type='Submit']").css({
      display: 'block',
      margin: '0 auto'
    });
});
```

Comment: We like pictures. We like code. But we usually don't like pictures of code. Please update your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: What are you trying to do with that selector? You're just targeting stuff that has an empty class attribute? Try `$('.mura-form-builder input[type="submit"])`. You can paste selectors into your developer console if you're unsure they're working.

Comment: This could also potentially be done with some CSS rules.  No javascript needed.

Comment: @j08691: I am unable to access the code that is present in the picture. That is why I am asking if there is an approach that I can do as I posted above that can target that particular div

Comment: @DominicTobias: What I am trying to do is look for a selector, which in this case it is blank, not sure why (again, the form is generated by the CMS) and add inline styling to that div that contains an empty class

Comment: @Taplar: How would I achieve it through CSS rules

Comment: You could take the selector that Dominic gave above and create a CSS rule for that with `.mura-form-builder input[type="submit"] { text-align:center }`, and if that doesn't work you could try `.mura-form-builder input[type="submit"] { text-align:center !important }` to try to force the rule if others are overriding it.  Pretty much most selectors that you come up with for targeting elements, can also be used as CSS rule definitions.

Comment: @Taplar: I tried that approach but the button is not effected

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
$("[class='']").css("text-align", "center");
```

you can use

```
$(".mura-form-builder input[type=submit]").parent().css("text-align", "center");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @ mjzeus: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, it doesn't affect the Submit button in the form

Answer (score 0):

Try with Class or id selector or input tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// class selector  $(".your selector class name").css("text-align", "center");
// id selector  $("# your selector id").css("text-align", "center");
// by input tag  $("input[type='text']").css("text-align", "center");
});
```

Comment: I have tried the approaches you have mentioned previously. It does not properly. I originally tried the following $("[class]").css("text-align", "center"); which targets everything that contains class

Comment: you want to add css on all div that have attribute classs?

Comment: @ Onkar: No. The selector in this case is blank. In the form, it appears as <div class>Input button</div> (as shown in the image above highlighted.). I am not sure why the div contains a blank selector but I was trying to target that particular selector and I thought if I did $("[class='']").css("text-align", "center"); it would target that blank selector but it does not

Comment: try this one:
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.mura-form-builder').children().last().css("text-align", "center");
});